# opam init fails - unable to create temp file

Tags: opam

I have installed opam 2.1.0 on a Linux Virtualbox VM. When I try `opam init`, I get the following error:

```
<><> Fetching repository information ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] Could not update repository "default": OpamDownload.Download_fail(_, "Curl
        failed: \"/snap/bin/curl --write-out %{http_code}\\\\n --retry 3
        --retry-delay 2 --user-agent opam/2.1.0 -L -o
        /tmp/opam-32196-d33843/index.tar.gz.part --
        https://opam.ocaml.org/index.tar.gz\" exited with code 23")
[ERROR] Initial download of repository failed.
```

Running with --disable-sandboxing doesn't help. I know that its a problem creating/writing to `/tmp/opam-...` directory because if I replace that with my current directory or home directory the command by itself runs fine. It also runs fine with `/tmp/opam-...` if I use the --create-dirs option in curl but I don't have any way of getting opam init to use that option. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The reason `opam init` failed for me was because curl was installed with snap on my system. This exactly what is going on with your VM.
Try to run `opam init -verbose` and that could reveal more about why you ran into an error.
In my case I needed to install other things with opam and it kept failing every time. So `snap uninstall curl` and then `sudo apt install curl` fixed things. (Was only able to figure this out with help from my professor)

**Workaround**

I ran into the same issue and I found a workaround on the OCaml forum: [here](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/opam-init-error-on-mac/2276/7). (Credits to UnixJunkie)

You can run:

```
opam init github git+https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository.git
```

This should avoid the certificate issues. This worked for me.

I tried to fix the certificate issues using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457157/) as well. You could try doing that, but it seems complicated when the workaround is to simply point it to the github repo directly.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69143209/).

Comment: for me curl isn't installed and even though that worked future commands don't work. I think. Perhaps curl is just updated not 100% sure.