# opam init fails to verify certificate

Tags: opam

On a **completely fresh ubuntu 18.04** VM I tried to install **opam**:

```
$ wget https://github.com/ocaml/opam/releases/download/2.1.0/opam-2.1.0-x86_64-linux
$ mv opam-2.1.0-x86_64-linux opam
$ chmod 777 opam
$ ./opam init
```

And here is the error I got

```
<><> Fetching repository information ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
[ERROR] Could not update repository "default": OpamDownload.Download_fail(_,
        "Download command failed: \"/usr/bin/wget --content-disposition -t 3 -O
        /tmp/opam-5936-f23d09/index.tar.gz.part -U opam/2.1.0 --
        https://opam.ocaml.org/index.tar.gz\" exited with code 5 \"ERROR:
        cannot verify opam.ocaml.org's certificate, issued by
        \226\128\152CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t)\\\\
        ,OU=Zscaler Inc.,O=Zscaler Inc.,ST=California,C=US\226\128\153:\"")
[ERROR] Initial download of repository failed.
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and I found a workaround on the OCaml forum: [here](https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/opam-init-error-on-mac/2276/7). (Credits to UnixJunkie)

You can run:

```
opam init github git+https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository.git
```

This should avoid the certificate issues. This worked for me.

I tried to fix the certificate issues using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69457157/) as well. You could try doing that, but it seems complicated when the workaround is to simply point it to the github repo directly.

**Update**

The reason `opam init` failed for me was because curl was installed with snap on my system.
Try to run `opam init -verbose` and that could reveal more about why you ran into an error.
In my case I needed to install other things with opam and it kept failing every time. So `snap uninstall curl` and then `sudo apt install curl` fixed things. (Was only able to figure this out with the help from my professor)